# Start scrolling command prompt when filled until a particular fraction

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm using the default terminal command prompt on Ubuntu 12.04. When I'm doing something on the prompt (as opposed to editing in `VI`) the scrolling starts when the text reaches bottom of the screen. I don't like that because I have to keep my eyes always at the bottom of the screen. I would prefer if there were an option to start scrolling things up when we reach a particular fraction of vertical screen size. Currently I just use clear screen (`CTRL+L`) but it's tedious to do that every time. I don't like resizing command prompt because the background distracts me and I have to resize it each time in a new session. Is there some way to do scroll when prompt fills until a particular fraction (say 70%)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using gnome-terminal as my console and it respects the [vt100 set scroll region](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Control-Sequences.html) Control character Sequence.

```
$ cat setscroll.sh 
function min(){
  if [[ $1 -le $2 ]]; then echo $1; else echo $2; fi
}

function max(){
  if [[ $1 -ge $2 ]]; then echo $1; else echo $2; fi
}

function setscrollregion(){
  CLR="\033[2J"
  SRGN="\033[1;"$1"r"
  echo -ne $CLR$SRGN
}

function calcline(){

  set `stty size` $1            # ;echo height=$1 width=$2 perc=$3
  bline=$(( ($1 * $3 ) / 100  ))    # calculate bottom line
  bline=$( min $bline $1)       # max is screen height
  bline=$( max 5 $bline)        # min is 5 lines customise as you wish
  echo $bline
}

setscrollregion $(calcline $1)
```

Then,

$ bash ./setscroll.sh 50

will set the scroll region to 50% of height